# effective way of transformation from 2D to 1D vector

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization

i want to create  1D  vector  in matlab from given  matrix,for this i have implemented following  algorithm ,which use trivial way

```
% create   one dimensional vector from 2D  matrix
function [x]=one_dimensional(b,m,n) 
 k=1;
 for i=1:m 
     for  t=1:n
         x(k)=b(i,t);
         k=k+1;
     end
 end
  x;
end
```

when i run it using following  example,it  seems to do it's task  fine

```
b=[2 1 3;4 2 3;1 5 4]

b =

     2     1     3
     4     2     3
     1     5     4

>> one_dimensional(b,3,3)

ans =

     2     1     3     4     2     3     1     5     4
```

but generally i know that,arrays  are not good way  to use in matlab,because it's performance,so what should be effective  way  for transformation  matrix into row/column vector?i am just care about performance.thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `(:)` operator...But it works on columns not rows so you need to transpose using the `'`operator before , for example:

```
b=b.';
b(:)'

ans=
   2     1     3     4     2     3     1     5     4
```

and I transposed again to get a row output (otherwise it'll the same vector only in column form)

or also, this is an option (probably a slower one):

```
reshape(b.',1,[])
```

Comment: so first transpose and then  use it b(:)'?

Comment: yes, or see the second option I've added. Also it is free to experiment code so don't be shy to use the line I wrote and see for yourself.